# Objective C: How do I add custom table view cells to a subview of a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I currently have a UIViewController displaying a map view. I would like to display some custom table view cells when I tap on a button within the same UIViewController. Can I do that? Or do I need to set the table view cells within a UITableViewController?

Thanks for any advise here.

Zhen Hoe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `UIViewController` subclass rather than a subclass of `UITableViewController` to manage a table view if the view to be managed is composed of multiple subviews, one of which is a table view. The default behavior of the `UITableViewController` class is to make the table view fill the screen between the navigation bar and the tab bar (if either are present).

> I would like to display some custom table view cells when I tap on a button within the same UIViewController.

If you want to show your table view along with other views, you can add a `UITableView` subview and make your controller implement `UITableViewDelegate`and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols.

Comment: thanks for the advise. Just to clarify, for this case, I need to first create a UIView to contain the tableView (i.e. [self.containerView addsubView:tableView]?

Comment: @Zhen you can add the table view directly (if you want) to the view that your controller manages like `[self.view addSubview:myTableView];` or to another subview.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `UITableViewController`, and then set the contents of the `UITableViewCells` using the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delegate method.